# Bootstrap Dropdown Not Working in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an issue with a Bootstrap dropdown menu. Few weeks ago it was opening with no problem in all the browsers, now I tested it in both Firefox and Chrome and they don't seem to work anymore. It only works in Internet Explorer and on mobile phones.
Here is the code that contains it:

```
echo '
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span> Menu <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="profile.php?id=' . $_SESSION["unique"] . '"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Profile</a></li>
            <li class="' . $class4 . '"><a href="about.php" target="_blank"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> About</a></li>
            <li><a href="logout.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Sign out</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>';
```

I am aware that the bug may not be in the code posted above but it's weird. The code should have no bug. It works perfectly except this and just in some browsers.

The browsers can open other dropdowns and yeah, I tried to update them.

Here is the site (in construction, of course):
http://logicwebschool.com

You can view the menu just by registering and logging in but I created an account for this purpose:

Email: no@email.com

Username: stackoverflow

Password: 123456

Thanks for taking your time to help me :)

Comment: I logged in and checked the application, and on the page in the network tool of browser, I observed that`bootstrap.min.js` is not being loaded you can try `<script src="scriptfile.js"></script>` instead of `<script data-rocketsrc="scriptfile.js"></script>`

Comment: Oh... I forgot to tell you that I use CloudFlare and that I selected a Code Minify option or something like that. I do use `<script src="name.js"></script>` - they are from Bootstrap CDN but are getting minified by CF.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for a response anymore. The Cloudflare Rocket Loader was the problem, I disabled it and everything is working now :D

Comment: `<script data-rocketsrc="scriptfile.js"></script>` was the issue right???

Comment: Yes but it wasn't written by me it was part of Cloudflare's automatic process. They have some other requirements in order to make the Rocket Loader work properly. So I disabled it for now.

Comment: Please post it as answer and accept it to close the question

Comment: I can do it just tomorrow. This is the thing with self-answering. :( You need to wait two days.